# Issue with page refresh

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm having issue with page refresh, every time I press refresh button on the browser when I'm on page different then index I get "Server Error in '/' Application." 404 error Page.

The back forward button works correctly, but not the refresh.

When I use http://localhost:2902/#/Dashboard?id=1
it works

When I use http://localhost:2902/Dashboard?id=1
it doesn't

How can I fix it?

```
var dashboardRoutes = function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode({
                                            enabled: true,
                                            requireBase: false
});

$stateProvider
    .state('stateIndex', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            "mainView": {
                templateUrl: '/Dashboards/List',
                controller: 'dashListController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('stateList', {
        url: '/List',
        views: {
            "mainView": {
                templateUrl: '/Dashboards/List',
                controller: 'dashListController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('stateDashboard', {
        url: '/Dashboard?id',
        views: {
            "mainView": {
                templateUrl: function (params) { return '/Dashboards/Dashboard?id=' + params.id; },
                controller: 'dashboardController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('stateWidgetsList', {
        url: '/WidgetsList',
        views: {
            "mainView": {
                templateUrl: '/Dashboards/WidgetsList',
                controller: 'widgetsListController'
            }
        }
    });
}
dashboardRoutes.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider'];
```

RouteConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Index",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboards", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Dashboard",
            url: "Dashboards/Dashboard/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboards", action = "Dashboard", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboards", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just your server settings, nothing to do with AngularJS.

You should setup you server to make this URL "http://localhost:2902/Dashboard?id=1" also lead to **index.html** but not to Dashboard directory.

Comment: but I don't want that. I would like the page to refresh and displays Dashboard with the Id  = 1

Comment: man, is it single page app or not? if yes - all should go to index.html

Comment: It is SPA,  so yes it should go to index but it should display different content than may index ( as first/default ) page

Comment: there are 2 routers in our story: server one - that should always go to index.html, and your application AngularJS one - that will provide right content

Comment: Are you mean the RouteConfig in ASP.Net ?

Comment: may be, I don't know specific of you server

Comment: I have included my ASP.Net RouteConfig in the question

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have enabled the `html5mode`, to remove the # you need to enable `html5mode` , which you have done correctly but you also need to implement URL-rewrite on your server to make it work correctly , otherwise after refresh server won't able to be locate the html file.

Comment: ok. At the moment I only run this on my local IIS Express. Do you have any link with details how to do this?

Comment: the rewrite is only needed if you want your application to run on non-html5 browser version ,otherwise this link will help you in what you need to achieve : https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag